# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc virtual method not shown

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using identical ASP.NETCoreAll packages for two separate solutions, not sure why in one solution the intellisense(object library) does not present the public virtual OkObjectResult Ok(object value). I can see the OKResult object but the Ok method is absent. Any insight is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBj4U.png) appreciated.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Creates an Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult object that produces an Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status200OK
    //     response.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   value:
    //     The content value to format in the entity body.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual OkObjectResult Ok(object value);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did not have Inherited Controller Base Class referenced! Goofball oversight.